# How do I select the first elements of each list in a list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I am trying to isolate the first words in a series of sentences using Python/ NLTK.

created an unimportant series of sentences (the_text) and while I am able to divide that into tokenized sentences, I cannot successfully separate just the first words of each sentence into a list (first_words).

[['Here', 'is', 'some', 'text', '.'], ['There', 'is', 'a', 'a', 'person', 'on', 'the', 'lawn', '.'], ['I', 'am', 'confused', '.'], ['There', 'is', 'more', '.'], ['Here', 'is', 'some', 'more', '.'], ['I', 'do', "n't", 'know', 'anything', '.'], ['I', 'should', 'add', 'more', '.'], ['Look', ',', 'here', 'is', 'more', 'text', '.'], ['How', 'great', 'is', 'that', '?']]

```
the_text="Here is some text. There is a a person on the lawn. I am confused. "
the_text= (the_text + "There is more. Here is some more. I don't know anything. ")
the_text= (the_text + "I should add more. Look, here is more text. How great is that?")

sents_tok=nltk.sent_tokenize(the_text)
sents_words=[nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sents_tok]
number_sents=len(sents_words)
print (number_sents)
print(sents_words)
for i in sents_words:
    first_words=[]
    first_words.append(sents_words (i,0))
print(first_words)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried `i[0]` instead of `sents_words (i,0)`? Also, put `first_words = []` before the loop, or you clear it with every iteration.

Comment: are you looking for this list -`['Here', 'There', 'I', 'There', 'Here', 'I', 'I', 'Look', 'How']`? The just use `firstwords = [i[0] for i in your_list]`

Comment: This is a basic python task, there are no nltk-specific aspects. Do as @letsc says in the comment above, and pay attention to round vs. square brackets in general.

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems with your code, and you have to fix all three to make it work:

```
for i in sents_words:
    first_words=[]
    first_words.append(sents_words (i,0))
```

First, you're erasing `first_words` each time through the loop: move the `first_words=[]` outside the loop.

Second, you're mixing up function calling syntax (parentheses) with indexing syntax (brackets): you want `sents_words[i][0]`.

Third, `for i in sents_words:` iterates over the *elements* of `sents_words`, not the indices. So you just want `i[0]`. (Or, alternatively, `for i in range(len(sents_words))`, but there's no reason to do that.)

So, putting it together:

```
first_words=[]
for i in sents_words:
    first_words.append(i[0])
```

---

If you know anything about [comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), you may recognize that this pattern (start with an empty list, iterate over something, appending some expression to the list) is exactly what a list comprehension does:

```
first_words = [i[0] for i in sents_words]
```

If you don't, then either now is a good time to learn about comprehensions, or don't worry about this part. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> sents_words = [['Here', 'is', 'some', 'text', '.'],['There', 'is', 'a', 'a', 'person', 'on', 'the', 'lawn', '.'], ['I', 'am', 'confused', '.'], ['There', 'is', 'more', '.'], ['Here', 'is', 'some', 'more', '.'], ['I', 'do', "n't", 'know', 'anything', '.'], 'I', 'should', 'add', 'more', '.'], ['Look', ',', 'here', 'is', 'more', 'text', '.'], ['How', 'great', 'is', 'that', '?']]
```

You can use a loop to `append` to a `list` you've initialized previously:

```
>>> first_words = []
>>> for i in sents_words:
...     first_words.append(i[0])
...
>>> print(*first_words)
Here There I There Here I I Look How
```

or a comprehension (replace those square brackets with parentheses to create a generator instead):

```
>>> first_words = [i[0] for i in sents_words]
>>> print(*first_words)
Here There I There Here I I Look How
```

or if you don't need to save it for later use, you can directly print the items:

```
>>> print(*(i[0] for i in sents_words))
Here There I There Here I I Look How
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to access items in lists and list of lists:

```
>>> fruits = ['apple','orange', 'banana']
>>> fruits[0]
'apple'
>>> fruits[1]
'orange'
>>> cars = ['audi', 'ford', 'toyota']
>>> cars[0]
'audi'
>>> cars[1]
'ford'
>>> things = [fruits, cars]
>>> things[0]
['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
>>> things[1]
['audi', 'ford', 'toyota']
>>> things[0][0]
'apple'
>>> things[0][1]
'orange'
```

For you problem:

```
>>> from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
>>> 
>>> the_text="Here is some text. There is a a person on the lawn. I am confused. There is more. Here is some more. I don't know anything. I should add more. Look, here is more text. How great is that?"
>>> 
>>> tokenized_text = [word_tokenize(s) for s in sent_tokenize(the_text)]
>>> 
>>> first_words = []
>>> # Iterates through the sentneces.
... for sent in tokenized_text:
...     print sent
... 
['Here', 'is', 'some', 'text', '.']
['There', 'is', 'a', 'a', 'person', 'on', 'the', 'lawn', '.']
['I', 'am', 'confused', '.']
['There', 'is', 'more', '.']
['Here', 'is', 'some', 'more', '.']
['I', 'do', "n't", 'know', 'anything', '.']
['I', 'should', 'add', 'more', '.']
['Look', ',', 'here', 'is', 'more', 'text', '.']
['How', 'great', 'is', 'that', '?']
>>> # First words in each sentence.
... for sent in tokenized_text:
...     word0 = sent[0]
...     first_words.append(word0)
...     print word0
...     
... 
Here
There
I
There
Here
I
I
Look
How

>>> print first_words ['Here', 'There', 'I', 'There', 'Here', 'I', 'I', 'Look', 'How']
```

In one-liner with list comprehensions:

```
# From the_text, you extract the first word directly
first_words = [word_tokenize(s)[0] for s in sent_tokenize(the_text)]

# From tokenized_text
tokenized_text= [word_tokenize(s) for s in sent_tokenize(the_text)]
first_words = [w[0] for s in tokenized_text]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, although it's pretty much similar to abarnert's suggestion:

```
first_words = []
for i in range(number_sents):
    first_words.append(sents_words[i][0])
```